# Using sql CONTAINS in a Rails 3 .where statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have the following statement in my model:

```
.where("ClinicalText LIKE 'Paid by PET HEALTH' AND PVID != 44444")
```

I need to find all records where the `ClinicalText` contains one of the following:

```
Paid by PET HEALTH
Paid by PET HEALTH(T)
Paid by PET HEALTH (T)
```

I thought my like statement would cover all options seeing as they all contain the '    Paid by PET HEALTH'.

It would appear I was wrong and now need to find the right syntax.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you should be able to use the '%' wildcard.

```
.where("ClinicalText LIKE 'Paid by PET HEALTH%' AND PVID != 44444")
```

Of course this will get ANYTHING that starts with the string 'Paid by PET HEALTH' (depending on your MySQL settings this may or may not be case sensitive.)

EDIT: this answer only uses one wildcard to limit the match against strings that start with the necessary string. If you want to match anywhere in the value, then add a '%' to the front as well.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` needs wildcards

`.where("ClinicalText LIKE '%Paid by PET HEALTH%' AND PVID != 44444")`